# Simplecart's paypal checkout currency

Tags: javascript, paypal, checkout, simplecart

Why is it my Paypal checkout keep showing in USD? Even I have manage to change the simplecart currency, and its showing the right currency when item in shelf have added into the cart. But the moment I click on the checkout button, the Paypal page would show everything in USD currency. E.g RM10 into $10 USD.

```
  simpleCart.email = "my@email.com";
  simpleCart.checkoutTo = PayPal;
  simpleCart.currency = MYR;
  simpleCart.taxRate  = 0.02;
```

I even changed this,

> ```
>         case DKK:
>           return "Rp&nbsp;";
>         case MYR:
>           return "RM";
>         case USD:
>         case CAD:
>         case AUD:
>         case NZD:
>         case HKD:
>         case SGD:
>           return "&#36;";
>         default:
>           return "";
>       }
>     };
>     me.currencyStringForPaypalCheckout = function( value ){
>       if( me.currencySymbol() == "RM" ){
>         return "RM" + parseFloat( value ).toFixed(2);
>       } else {
>         return "" + parseFloat(value ).toFixed(2);
>       }
>     };
> ```

Where did it went wrong? Is it my cart or the checkout that becomes the problem?

Comment: This also happens to me when I change the simple cart currency to simple EUR. It shows as EUR throughout the webpage but on PayPal's api currency is changed to USD. why?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, because MYR isn't a build in currency. You have to set the currency like this:

```
simpleCart.currency({
    code: "MAC" ,
    name: "My Awesome Currency" ,
    symbol: " $AWE" ,
    delimiter: " " ,
    decimal: "," ,
    after: true
});
```

I don't know what your method `currencySymbol()` returns, but have a look at this snippet from the [docs](http://simplecartjs.org/documentation/currency):

```
simpleCart.currency();  // returns { code:"MAC", symbol:"$AWE", name:"My Awesome Curency" }
```